# I want to host webserver befind Wi-fi router which is using Static IP.

Tags: dns

Before purchasing Dedicated server I want to hone my skills. Therefore I want to install Ubuntu on my desktop which is connected to Wi-fi router.  I am using static IP provided by my ISP. the cable modem is connected to router.  All my laptops get dynamic ip from router.

I want to connect to my dedicated server located at my home, from my office also.  I am confused as to which IP I should use for DNS.  How can I access A machine which is using Wi-fi router for internet connection.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use dynamic dns to give your external ip from your cable modem a name. Then you need to open a port on your wifi router to pass through to the Ubuntu box. Please note that many if not all ISP's block port 80 from being accessed.

Here's some helpful docs for you:

Dynamic DNS: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS

Port forwarding your router: http://portforward.com/